# Concurrent DDL error while using datashare in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

Can someone please explain this particular constraint for Redshift datashare?

> Amazon Redshift doesn't support accessing a datashare object which had
> a concurrent DDL occur between the Prepare and Execute of the access.

I'm seeing this error pop up frequently but I have no idea what is causing it.

**Actual Error**
Concurrent DDL committed on foo.bar between Prepare and Execute (SQLSTATE XX000)","time":"2023-10-06T18:22:48Z"}

We have two Redshift clusters, one provisioned and one serverless. The data is pushed into Redshift serverless cluster and a datashare is setup between the serverless and provisioned Redshift cluster. The problem occurs on read from the provisioned Redshift cluster.